# Why cannot embed a SplitLayoutPanel into a HTMLPanel in GWT?

Tags: gwt

When I try to embed a SplitLayoutPanel into a HTMLPanel, the page became blank. Any problems here?

Comment: This isn't very detailed, so you might not get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SplitLayoutPanel implements RequiresResize interface, but HTMLPanel does not implement ProvidesResize interface. As a result, SplitLayoutPanel has a height of zero.

You will have to set height of SplitLayoutPanel explicitly or through CSS, or you can use a different container for SplitLayoutPanel that implements ProvidesResize (e.g. LayoutPanel).

Comment: Wow, that explains everything. Thanks very much!